# Как подключиться к удалённой базе данных mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh

Есть проблема. Если я пытаюсь подключится к серверу с помощью ssh, а потом уже на сервере захожу в mysql, всё работает нормально. Если же я пытаюсь подключится к базе данных на прямую - `mysql -h HOST -u USER -p PASSWORD`, выдаёт ошибку - `Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user`. Всё делаю на ubuntu. Из-за чего это может быть? Может надо как-то подтвердить доступ к базе или ещё что-то? Раньше с такой проблемой не сталкивался.

Comment: Скорее всего отсутствует указанный при авторизации пользователь.

Comment: Нет, пользователь верный я проверил.

Comment: *пользователь верный я проверил* Полностью, включая хост?

Comment: Всё, спасибо, разобрался. Надо было в host поставить %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, спасибо, разобрался. Надо было в host поставить %.